# Fat Cowboy, a Skinny Cowboy, and a Prostitute

Tags: identify-this-movie, western

It was around 1995 that I watched this cowboy movie. It think it was not very popular and not a high grade movie. I just want to watch it again because that was **the first cowboy movie that I watched**. I was about 10 years only and I didn't understand English.

The story goes like this:- Two cowboys, one thin and one fat were riding on their horses. The thin one was the main hero, who was intelligent but the fat one was clumsy and always ran after women. The thin one always plays some small music instrument on his mouth, it could be a [Jew's harp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jew%27s_harp), I don't remember clearly. The fat one saw a beautiful prostitute bathing naked in a forest and fell in love with her. He went to the brothel, saw her coming down with a customer, paid the price to the pimp and made love with her. There was a mole on her buttock. There was a gang who disturbed people and they had a camp where they kept all their guns and explosives. They purchased a new machine gun and were celebrating it. The boss of that gang kidnapped that beautiful prostitute. After quarreling much, the two cowboys decided to rescue her. The fighting scenes were good and funny. The prostitute was rescued and the hero destroyed the camp with a dynamite. The fat guy and the prostitute were together happily. The last scene I remember was where the hero secretly threw the coffee prepared by the fat guy and his girlfriend(the prostitute) because it didn't taste good.

Comment: Sounds like a film with the duo: Terence Hill & Bud Spencer.

Comment: @Larme The only problem is that Bud Spencer (the fat one) usually isn't the one running after the women. The plot sounds vaguely like _My name is Trinity_ where Terence Hill (the thin one) gets engaged to two Mormon women.

Comment: Indeed, that was a strange fact, but it could be inexact from his/her memory. But still, I think that name them could be a nice suggestion to identify the protagonists since they are a famous duo.

Comment: Was this movie black and white? Can you say whether this movie would be considered a B movie, spaghetti western, etc.? Any additional information would be helpful.

Comment: Damn it I know this movie! It was some sort of Spencer/Hill clone (if you can believe it). Now I need to remember what it was called...

Comment: @dmcgill50 I think it was in color, yes it was. I was too small, I couldn't differentiate the quality or genre of a movie. That was one of the few western movies we had in our village. We watched it again and again as there was no other to watch. That's why I still remember the story but I don't remember the faces in that movie. I guest it's hard to forget childhood memories.

Comment: Where did you grow up?

Comment: @dmcgill50 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizoram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based off your description and an [extensive search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=&as_oq=prostitute%20jew%20harp&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=spaghetti-western.net&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&hl=en&lr=&q=prostitute%20OR%20jew%20OR%20harp%20site:spaghetti-western.net&start=10), I believe that I found your childhood western, [Los Amigos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Amigos). It also goes by *Deaf Smith & Johnny Ears*.

From Wikipedia:

> "...Johnny recognises a girl he earlier has watched taking a bath in the river as the prostitute Susie Q..."
>
> "...Deaf pays so he can spend a night with her..."
>
> "...They set a trap with explosives to blow up the weapons transport to Morton..."
>
> "...Instead they infiltrate Morton's fort and destroy his men with explosives and with the new weapon, a machine gun that Deaf can handle because he could read the lips of the instructor..."

Please let me know if this is the correct movie.